# How can deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Binary' in Azure CosmosDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have really  big trouble with AZURE CosmosDb during 1 week! İt makes me down. Everything is working in my local computer. But if I publish below code,
it returns me Below Error.

LOGS in Azure function in Azure:

2019-07-25T12:28:00.854 [Information] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 7/25/2019 12:28:00 PM
2019-07-25T12:28:00.888 [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=9e5758d7-7ffa-430a-85ee-178aeaa6758a)
***Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Binary'.***

CODE:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    [Obsolete]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("* * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        var connectionString = @"mongodb://gggdfdfgfsdfdsfsd";
        //var connectionString = @"mongodb://localhost:27017/admin";
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("xxxxx-playground");
        //var database = client.GetDatabase("abc");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Test>("test");

        var beforeDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
        var totalDeleted = 0;
        var ids = new List<ObjectId>();

        do
        {
            ids = collection.Find(k =>
                                  k.CreatedDate < beforeDate &&
                                  k.xxx == null &&
                                  k.yyy == null &&
                                  (k.Items.Length == 0 || k.Items == null)
                                  )

                            .Limit(100)
                            .Project(k => k._id)
                            .ToList();

            if (ids.Any())
            {
                collection.DeleteMany(k => ids.Contains(k._id));
                totalDeleted += ids.Count();
            }

        } while (ids.Any());

        log.LogInformation($"Deleted {totalDeleted} documents created before {beforeDate.ToShortDateString()}");
    }
}


public class Test
{

    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }


    public object xxx { get; set; }

    public object yyy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public object[] Items { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Can you try using `MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString()`; for id = ''

Comment: @HariHaran, I don't understand reason Why? I am getting collection and use delete process.Why or how GenerateNewId?

Comment: @Penguen run the following query on azure and see if it returns any results. `db.test.find( { _id: { $type: "binData" } } )` if it does return something, then the error message makes sense. one or more docs have the _id field stored as binary. changing that could/should fix your problem. just a thought though. i've never used azure functions.